# how to update web reference location

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, reference

i have an application wherein i am using a web-service. Now the ip address of the machine where this web-service was residing has changed.

i try to update the web reference in my application and it is still trying to access the web-service from the old location. How do i change this to the new location.

I have already updated the new location in my web.config file.

Please help!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the service, Choose configure and change the address.

Comment: i got an "Unspecified error" when i tried to do that. Altough it changed the ip. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an unspecified error you could always remove the existing reference (which will break the build, so don't check anything in), then add the new one.  Build and test to make sure it works and then check it in to source control.